# Issue with case when SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a table named 'candidate' which contains among others columns ,score_math' and 'score_language' reflecting candidate's score in respective tests. I need to

Show the number of students who scored at least 60 in both math and language   (versatile_candidates) and the number of students who scored below 40 in both of
   these tests (poor_candidates). Don't include students with NULL preferred_contact. My query is:

```
select 
count(case when score_math>=60 and score_language>=60 then 1 else 0
end) as versatile_candidates,
count(case when score_math<40 and score_language<40 then 1 else 0 end) as
poor_candidates
from candidate
where preferred_contact is not null
```

But this produces always total number of candidates wit not-null preferred contact type. Can't really figure out what I did wrong and more importantly why this doesn't work. [DBMS is Postgres if this matters ]Please help

Comment: Use `SUM()` not `COUNT()`

Comment: or don't use `else 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close - the reason you're getting the total number of all candidates is because `COUNT()` will count a `0` the same as a `1` (and any other non-`NULL` value, for that matter).  And since the values could only ever be `0` or `1`, your `COUNT()` will return the total number of all candidates.

Since you're already defaulting the cases that don't match to `0`, all you need to do is change the `COUNT()` to a `SUM()`:

```
Select  Sum(Case When score_math >= 60
                      And score_language >= 60 Then 1
                 Else 0
            End) As versatile_candidates
      , Sum(Case When score_math < 40
                      And score_language < 40 Then 1
                 Else 0
            End) As poor_candidates
From    candidate
Where   preferred_contact Is Not Null
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` does not take into consideration `NULL` values. All other values which are not NULL will be counted.

You might want to replace it with `SUM()`

Comment: Right. Should have used Sum() instead of count(). Many thanks, upvoting both answers!